# Stack addresses using gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb, stack, memory-address

I have got this hex addresses using the command "x /50gx $exp" on gdb:

```
0xbfffca44:     0xbfffdaa800279ff4      0x0804869008048583
0xbfffca54:     0x00000004bfffcaa0      0x0000000000000000
0xbfffca64:     0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
0xbfffca74:     0x0000000000000000      0x6b63736600000000
0xbfffca84:     0x006369676f6c656d      0x6b63736600000000
0xbfffca94:     0x006369676f6c656d      0x4141414100000000
0xbfffcaa4:     0x4141414141414141      0x0000000041414141
0xbfffcab4:     0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
```

I am trying to figure out what is the start address of the 41 sequence but I dont know how to calculate it.

Can anybody help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is a little endian machine, the actual order of the bytes in each integer is reversed, so reversing each integer value in the line:

```
0xbfffca94:     0x006369676f6c656d      0x4141414100000000
```

Gives us:

```
0xbfffca94:     6d 65 6c 6f 67 69 63 00      00 00 00 00 41 41 41 41
```

the first 41 is 12 (0xc) bytes from the start, so its address is `0xbfffcaa0 (0xbfffca94 + 0xc)`

Also - If you are interested in bytes, and not bigger integers, you can dump it with a different format, e.g. `x /400bx $esp`